# How to describe this code pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In several places of the code base I am working in, I see classes with these kinds of properties:

```
public class LinkEnd
{
    public Joint AssociatedJoint { get; set; }

    public Point Location
    {
        get
        {
            return AssociatedJoint.Location;
        }
        set
        {
            AssociatedJoint.Location = value;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there a formal term for this pattern of exposing a property of a property? I understand getters and setters, I am specifically interested in if there is a term describing a class representing a property as one of its own and backing that property with another encapsulated object's property.

Comment: I can't say for sure. But It looks like simple encapsulation to me. A way to start on the design path route is ask yourself what's the motivation or problem it's trying to solve.

Comment: One of the problems I can see it solving is if it is a commonly accessed property, This is a way to shorten the verbosity. `linkEnd.AssociatedJoint.Location` is more verbose than `linkEnd.Location`

Comment: OK, it's fair argument though that what you have in the comment would be "bad", but it depends. Personally, I don't see that as proper. The design is "saying" when you get the location it's the location of the `LinkEnd` not `AssociatedJoint`. Plus, I don't know about having the associated joint publicly acceptable. That property's isn't backed by a private attribute. So verbosity - I don't know... If fact, IMHO, the simple fact AssociatedJoint is public it makes it difficult to assign a pattern.

Comment: I don't know what to call this but the reason for it seems clear:  To avoid violating the Law of Dementer.

Comment: I vote for calling it an anti-pattern *as written* after a bit of thought because it appears "ineffective and risks being highly unproductive". The idea that you hide all but the most necessary information from the client is broken when you allow them to get at the `AssociatedJoint`. They can simply get it and "see" and use all it has to offer and you have no way of stopping it. This is *almost* good design but still not seeing a "pattern" in the context of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are not looking for a pattern but rather rule - law of demeter.

More: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Note that it doesn't mean you always can't access properties of other object directly. You just shouldn't access properties of different abstraction levels.

In example: what is better approach?

```
digestive_system = person.digestive_system()
stomach = digestive_system.stomach()
stomach.put(food)
```

versus

```
person.eat(food)
```

It's clear.